# Google apis adding events to calendar javascript

Tags: javascript, events, calendar, recurrence

I am trying to add a new event using javascript:

```
new_event = {
                          "summary": 'new event'
                          "location": 'Somewhere'
                          "start": {
                            "dateTime": "2015-01-14T17:00:00.000Z"
                          },
                          "end": {
                            "dateTime": "2015-01-14T18:00:00.000Z"
                          },
                          "reminders": {
                            "useDefault": false
                          }
                        }
```

After executing request I get 2 identical events.
If I try to add recurrence

```
new_event = {
                          "summary": 'new event'
                          "location": 'Somewhere'
                          "start": {
                            "dateTime": "2015-01-14T17:00:00.000Z"
                          },
                          "end": {
                            "dateTime": "2015-01-14T18:00:00.000Z"
                          },
                          "reminders": {
                            "useDefault": false

                          },
                           "recurrence": ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;RANGE=ENDAFTER;COUNT=4"]
                          }
```

I get the following error: 
 code: 400 , message: "Missing time zone definition for start time"

Comment: I solved the "Missing time zone definition for start time" error. A Timezone must be provided in case of recurrence. But I don't understand why I get 2 identical events with one request